# jquery alignment

Tags: jquery, alignment, product

I have added a nice little bit of jquery which make images black and white and when you hover over they turn to colour.

You can see this in effect here: 
http://www.emmaphillipsbridal.com/brides.html

I have now started to add products to my website and i think this bit of code is causing an alignment issue.

In safari everything is ok but on Firefox and chrome (I haven't checked IE) the images loads up and when they the query kicks in and the images turn to B&W they images bound to the right. You can see on this page:
http://www.emmaphillipsbridal.com/shop/dresses.html

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and what can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class "img_wrapper" remove position: absolute from the style on the second image in the div.  (Tested in Firebug)

Comment: Awesome, its working. thanks so much, I want to give you a tick up but i only have a ranking of 14 so i can't, it says i need 15!!!